# Change font color in shiny app side panel

Tags: html, r, shiny

How can I modify the font of individual checkbox items in a shiny app? I've tried:

```
checkboxGroupInput("trendsInput", "Add Trend Lines",
                         choices=c(tags$HTML("<font color='red'>All Typists</font>")="allTypists", 
                                   "All Selected User's Answers"="allThisUser", 
                                   "Same Question"="allQuestion", 
                                   "Same L1"="allL1", 
                                   "Same Cognitive Load"="allCogLoad"
                         ),
                         selected="allTypists")
```

But this does not compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with Javascript. Just add the code under your `checkboxGroupInput` (remember to add a `,`):

```
tags$script("$('input[value=\"allTypists\"]').parent().css('color','red');")
```

The code uses jQuery to find the `input` with the value of `allTypists`, and assign the css `color:red` to its parent (the actual label).

Comment: This is really great! Thank you! Is there a way I can use a hex code?

Comment: Yes any color code that works in standard CSS should work.

Comment: Sorry, where to put the code exactly? I am getting an error `Warning: Error in validateCssUnit: CSS units must be a single-element numeric or character vector` when I put this in the checkboxgroup and I don't see an effect if I put it after the checkboxgroup

Comment: @AlexKlindt this should put outside `checkboxGroupInput`, before or after it.